# Paperclip image uploads in Rails - Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to handle image uploads to rails. it worked fine on my dev OSX machine, but now on my web server I get this error:

```
[paperclip] /Users/marky/bin/identify '-format' '%wx%h' '/tmp/stream,16451,2.JPG[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError: Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError>
[paperclip] /Users/marky/bin/identify '-format' '%wx%h' '/tmp/stream,16451,2.JPG[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError: Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError>
```

Now it's clear to me the reason; identify is actually in  /usr/bin/ not /Users/marky/bin/ which is from my dev machine. I have:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin"
```

in my `development.rb`, but I'm still getting the error. I have no idea how to fix this, can anyone help?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as well.  It seems it has something to do with passenger in my case because it worked fine with mongrel.  Are you using passenger?

Comment: I was having similar error, but when I set Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin" in development.rb it works now. ps, I am on Heroku

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are hosting your application with Passenger, keep in mind that Passenger does not have the same $PATH variable as your logged in user.  A good way to check whether Passenger can see the ImageMagick commands is to add this to one of your erb templates:

```
<%= `which convert` %>
<%= `echo $PATH` %>
```

and to compare the results with running the same commands in your terminal.  Another possibility is ImageMagick can't find the libs it needs.  In this case, you may need to export another variable to let ImageMagick know where the libs are:

```
# my config/environments/development.rb
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='/Users/jch/Library/ImageMagick-6.6.3/lib' /Users/jch/Library/ImageMagick-6.6.3/bin"
```

Hope that helps -jerry

Comment: by the same token, you can just type in shell: heroku console %x{convert -version}+%x{which convert}

Comment: make sure you restart the server, after adding (or changing) the Paperclip.options[:command_path] to the environments/development.rb

Answer (score 17):

Install following packages for working with imagemagick

```
1) apt-get install imagemagick
2) apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
3) gem install rmagick
```

I think you are missing the second one.

Comment: apt-get install imagemagick 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
imagemagick is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-mpm-worker libapr1 libaprutil1-ldap apache2-utils apache2.2-common
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 apache2.2-bin ssl-cert libaprutil1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libmagickwand-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apache2-mpm-worker libapr1 libaprutil1-ldap apache2-utils apache2.2-common
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 apache2.2-bin ssl-cert libaprutil1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed



Thanks! Just ran all the above. Does that mean rmagick was actually not installed?

Answer (score 5):

You can install ImageMagick on your machine.
These problem generates because it will not find some methods.

To check ImageMagick is installed on your machine is simply run 'convert' command on terminal.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. yes I have ImageMagick installed on my machine. When I run the 'convert' command in the terminal it runs fine. any other ideas? it's clearly the path, but I have no idea how to change it.

Comment: ah, but if I run 'identify' from the command line it also runs fine no matter what folder I run it from, does this mean there is another problem?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, setting the Paperclip command path options under environment file for production server (NGINX + Passenger) didn't work.

I've set it in the paperclip.rb initializer file instead:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/" if Rails.env.production?
```

Comment: I had this issue after updating nginx. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have *imagemagick* installed by running

```
 which convert
```

in your console. In my case, the result was the following:

```
$ which convert
/usr/bin/convert
```

Then I add the following line to *config/environments/development.rb* which tells Paperclip where to find Imagemagick

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

Comment: If which convert shows /usr/bin/convert , in paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/" or aperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/convert/"